# Submit to software directories

Tags: software

I'd like to submit my free software to some of the online directories like Softonic.

Is there a tool to do this?

Comment: Create a pad file for your software.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools and services that will automatically submit your site to various directories; however, it can be dangerous to use them. Links from some directories can actually penalize your site in the search rankings.

It's always best to manually submit your site to each directory and take the time you need to format it best for that individual directory.

Build up a file with various pieces that you can copy-paste into the different directories to save you time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [digixmas directory submitter](http://www.digixmas.com/directory-submitter.php) (~2000 websites for $15 or ~150 websites for free). But another good way I found to submit sites is using [fiverr](http://fiverr.com/). There are many people that offer to manually submit your website, for only $5 - which I find awesome !